# Google maps error during visualization

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-maps, pug

I have a small directive that handle google map in my Angular application:

```
app.directive('googleMaps', function($rootScope, $q, $window){
   var mapLoader = $q.defer();
   function loadGoogleApi(key){
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = 'text/javascript';
       script.src= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + key + "&callback=initMap";
       $('body').append(script);
       return mapLoader.promise;
   };
   $window.initMap = function(){
       mapLoader.resolve();
   };
   return {
       restrinct: 'E',
       link: function($scope, element, attrs){
           loadGoogleApi('AIzaSyBtuQ-wYoHqnAxpXh8hTAfEH8BQCiBSCWw').then(function(){
               $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], {
                   zoom: 4,
                   center: { lat: 20, lng: 40 }
               });
               google.maps.event.trigger($scope.map,'resize');
           });

       }
   };
});
```

Then in my index.jade i have the following code:

```
//Other stuff
div.col.s12.m12.map-container
    h6="I miei spot"
    google-maps
```

All the initialization procedure succeeded but when I use the map on the website, I can see various strange graphic bug like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OeRg.png).

[image: image of resulting tiles]

I am using materialize.css and this simple css in that part of code:

```
google-maps { width: 100%; height: 300px;display: block; }
.map-container { height: 220px;margin-top: 10px; }
```

I don't understand why there is that bug, and i didn't found anything on internet about that bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing in my css file this line of code:

```
.map-container img { border-radius: 50%; }
```

It was a simple error of logic.