# Google Maps with dynamic markers Circular tiling issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Map with Markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUAO9.png)

[image]

I am getting this map as a result of following script:

```
<script>
       function Initialize() {

           google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
           var infowindow;
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "/api/Truck",
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               success: function (data) {
                   var Center = new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].CurrentLatitude, data[0].CurrentLongitude);

                   var mapOptions = {
                       zoom: 8,
                       center: Center,
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   };

                   var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap2"), mapOptions);
                   $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                           'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.CurrentLatitude, item.CurrentLongitude),
                           'map': gmap,
                           'title': item.TruckNumber
                       });
                       marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
                       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                           if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
                           infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<div class='infoDiv'><h3>" + item.TruckNumber + "</h3></div>" });

                           infowindow.open(gmap, marker);
                       });
                   });   

               }

           })
       }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
myMap2 { 
  width: 1041px; 
  height: 370px; 
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

I am just wondering why i am getting these circular tiles in map? i tried with differnt zooming values but still map shows these circles

Comment: You have an issue with your CSS (which you haven't provided).

Comment: related question: [Google maps error during visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007806/google-maps-error-during-visualization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CSS rule somewhere on your page which is inherited by the map `<div>` which is equivalent to the following:

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q20mwbex/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]