# Bad visualization with Google Maps Javascript

Tags: html, css, google-maps, bootstrap-4

I'm adding a map by Google Maps in my website but I don't know why it stretches and get grey sections and rounded borders inside.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="p-5 col-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center map-container">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            // Create the map with no initial style specified.
            // It therefore has default styling.
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {
                    lat: 38.9340635, 
                    lng: 16.2328417
                },
                zoom: 10,
                scrollwheel: false,
                dropPins: true,
                panBy: [0,0],
                tilt: 0,
                heading: 0,
                mapType: 'roadmap',
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                overviewMapControl: false,
                plusMinusZoom: false
            });
        }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCAeasy64XNqw6_DVPPmqX1cnqJNqSu7CU&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

And the only CSS about it:

```
.map-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
#map {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: Google maps]

What's happening?

Comment: I think your bootstrap flex classes must be messing with it. Remove those parent elements and just leave `#map`. Does it look normal?

Comment: Please include all the code to repro the issue.

Comment: related question: [Google Maps with dynamic markers Circular tiling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098662/google-maps-with-dynamic-markers-circular-tiling-issue)

Comment: why are you downvoting this question? is a real issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a CSS rule on images in the same section of the map with

```
border-radius: 15px;
max-height: 40%;
```

I solved this creating a class for that image and assigning these rules to that class.

Comment: please do not downvote this question, it was a real problem for me. if i had wrong with something please comment before.